# Como aplicar limit y skip a un arreglo de objetos dentro de un documento de mongo

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

estoy trabajando con mongoose en un projecto de node y necesito hacer una consulta a una coleccion con uno parametros, esto no es problema, lo que me causa dificultades es que dentro del documento que me devuelve esta consulta hay un arreglo de ids que es demasiado grade, y no se como seleccionar y aplicarle un limit() y un skip() solo a este array dentro del documento, se que se puede hacer algo como

```js
document.find({_id: ObjectId('aushgd78da7dusdkajs')}).skip(3).limit(5)
```

y esto me devolveria algo como

```js
[{
  _id: ObjectId("aushgd78da7dusdkajs"),
  list:[
      ObjectId("asdasd8a9s8dsa987d"),
      ObjectId("asdasd8a9s8dsds83d"),
      ObjectId("asdasd8a9s8dsds83d"),
      ObjectId("asdasd8a9s8dsdsdss"),
      ObjectId("asdasd8a9s8dsds856"),
      ...
  ]
}]
```

pero esos metodos se ejecutan en sobre la coleccion, no sobre el array dentro de la respuesta.

habira alguna manera de aplicar los metodos limit() y skip() sobre list y no sobre el documento?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Con mucho gusto te ayudo, pero necesito que escribas un [mcve]. Por lo menos para saber la estructura del documento sobre el cual estás realizando la consulta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) en la siguiente estructura:

```js
document.find({
  _id: ObjectId('aushgd78da7dusdkajs')
}, {
  list: {
    $slice: -5
  }
})
```

El segundo parametro es un objeto y necesitas poner `tuCampo:1` para que se muestren los que sean necesarios. En este caso le pasamos `$slice` a `list` para que solo nos retorne una parte del arreglo. `-5` significa que tomara los ultimos 5.

### EDICION

Agrega un arreglo donde el primer parámetro defina el indice donde debe empezar y el segundo la cantidad de elementos a mostrar.

```
document.find({
  _id: ObjectId('aushgd78da7dusdkajs')
}, {
  list: {
    $slice: [1,5]
  }
})
```

Comment: vale, este me funciono para limitar el numero de objetos en ese array, gracias. Ahora, habra alguna manera de ademas de limitarlo, indicar en la consulta, que me tome 5 registros apartir de x punto, es que lo que busco es mostrar lo dsatos de este list en una tabla  de un front, y lo que busco es hacer una consulta que me permita paginarlos en la tabla

Comment: @AlejandroCastellanos actualize la respuesta.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias